# Minimum size to get an accuracy spectral density using Fourier transformation

Tags: numerical-methods, random-variables, signal-processing

To get an accuracy result of spectral densities using Fourier transformation for a domain with the size $n$ by $n$. The minimum size of the input domain is $2n-1$ by $2n - 1$.

Is it true? Sorry, maybe this is a stupid question.  Thanks!

Comment: Fourier, not Fouriere. In fact, you are dealing with **2D discrete Fourier transform**, otherwise (improperly) called **2D fft**. Your question "is doubling the size of the input gives a precise output" is not stupid but it depends so much on what you want to do with this fft transform (peaks detection, for example ?). One cannot say yes or no to such a question. Have you been introduced to Shannon Theorem ?

Comment: @JeanMarie thank you so much for your response. I am checking the autocorrelation structure of a random field by using 2D or 3D FFT. In this case, if there is an isotropic field. The result after the fftshift operation is quasi symmetric. So the distance between the boundary of the result and the middle point of the result is $n/2$ or $n/2 - 1$. So if I want to evaluate the autocorrelation structure within distance n. The input field should be $2n-1$. This increases the computational cost.